# IE10 find first button on page and trigger click event on input submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, internet-explorer-10

sorry about title, i know its messy but i dont know how can i describe this situation.

we have an input field. but no form element. here is the code

```
<input name="search" id="search" onkeypress="SearchBox(this.value);" type="text" value="Search"/>
<input name="searchbutton" align="left" class="okbutton" id="searchbutton" onclick="SearchBox(search.value);" type="button"/>
```

SearchBox function checking keycode and if it is 13 (enter button charcode) sending search request. this code works in IE8/9 but in IE10 have interesting behaviour.

above code middle of the page. and we have a button element top of the page for LOGIN.

in IE10;

i enter a word in input and press enter:

- SearchBox function work,
- but behave like LOGIN button is clicked also and its a problem

note:sorry about language, english is not my native language.
note 2: SearchBox() function removed. check the jsfiddle link for the latest code.

Comment: Those `input`s share the same eventhandler. Please post the code for the `SearchBox() `, we'll see what is going on.

Comment: sorry for late, http://jsfiddle.net/Ag9dr/

Comment: Can you add the code for your javascript SearchBox() function?

Comment: i removed SearchBox() function you can view from jsfiddle.

Comment: Hmm... What you mean you removed `SearchBox()`..? That's the one we want to see. There won't be any conflicts in console though... : (.

Comment: forget searchbox(). open http://jsfiddle.net/Ag9dr/ in chrome. open debugger via F12 and look at the console. if you write something or click search button. as you can see console.log is writing what you entered in text field. if you hit enter also writing what you entered in text field. but open that adress with internet explorer. write sometihing text field end hit the enter. console will change and also an alert box will come.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

another solution

define your buttons type as button. because default type is submit

```
<button type="button" ....
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tested, it seems I've tumbled with that test. Anyway, this answer is worth of an upvote ;).

Answer (score 3):

Well, IE10 for Windows7 is a pre-release, and this seems to be one of the things MS should fix. Anyway, I don't know why this happens, but I've found a workaround for the problem:

Instead of `button`, use `<input type="button">`.

Live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtQNA/).

Comment: thx for reply. additional info; i am using windows 8 + IE 10, didnt try IE10 on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  Adding type="button" to all my buttons worked.
  <button type="button">...

Even though my buttons are not in a form.

From other testing I've done IE 10 works exactly like Chrome.  This is the only exception I've seen.