# IE10 Event Handling for button ng-click and ng-keyup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-10, angularjs-ng-click

In my HTML file, I have a text box and a button, and they are not related in any ways. The weird thing is that when I enter text into the **text box and hit enter** on the keyboard, it actually runs **the function connected to the button's** ng-click attribute. This **only happens on IE10,** but not IE11 or any other browers.

Any idea why this might be happening?

HTML

```
<h3>Group Fields  <input id="groupfields" ng-keyup="fr_group_update($event)"  ng-model="groupfields"></h3>

<div>
  <button ng-click="purge_tasks()">Purge Selection</button> <br/>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.fr_group_update = function(event){ 
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("This should run");
    }
};

$scope.purge_tasks = function(event){ 
    alert("This runs instead");
};
```

Comment: can you provide it in fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: how about ie9 and i8 ?

Comment: instead of <button> use <input type="button">  or<button type=:button"> and check if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE10 [seems to handle buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497606/ie10-find-first-button-on-page-and-trigger-click-event-on-input-submit) with no `type` property as if they were submit buttons. So when you press enter on any input on the page, it triggers the first button it finds.

You can easily fix that by explicitly setting the `type` attribute as `button`:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="purge_tasks()">Purge Selection</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular form used to have an interesting behaviour: if there is only one button in the form, it sets the form submit to the click of that button. When you press Enter in the textbox, you trigger the form submit.

Now I don't know why this is IE version specific, but this is the closest thing I can tell. Maybe IE 10 is doing something similar even without a form.

If you don't need and don't have a form, add one around the button, or try setting the type to button explicitly and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For IE a clean/fast solution (at least in my case):

```
$event.stopPropagation();
```

HTML

```
<h3>Group Fields  <input id="groupfields" ng-keyup="fr_group_update($event)"  ng-model="groupfields"></h3>

<div>
  <button ng-click="purge_tasks()">Purge Selection</button> <br/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.fr_group_update = function(event){ 
    $event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("This should run");
    }
};
$scope.purge_tasks = function(event){ 
    alert("This runs instead");
};
```